# slight modifications to a string re.findall python3

Tags: python, string, parsing

i use Python 3.6. I am currently searching for a string in a read.txt file. However, is there a way to produce slight modifications to that string? I give you an example with the code I have:

```
lines = [] # create an empty list
str1 = "as a result, we will comply with such standard"
with open(read.txt, 'r') as f:
  line2 = f.read()
  var1 = re.findall(str1, line2, re.I) # find str1 in read.txt
  if len(var1) > 0:
     lines.append('1') # if it exists, append a 1 to the list "lines"
  else:
     lines.append('0') # otherwise a 0
```

My problem is that I want the "re.findall" function also to look at the same str1 but without the "will" tense. This is, also to look at str1' = "as a result, we comply with such standard". Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated!

Thanks for your time anyways,

Comment: Are you sure regex is the right tool to do this ?

Comment: regex is definitely not the tool to use here - simple `in` lookup with multiple predefined patterns is more than enough, and since the patterns change they are not really `regular` it's not just the performance a reason to not use regex here.

Answer (score 2):

```
In [29]: str1 = "as a result, we (will ){0,1}comply with such standard"

In [30]: re.search(str1, str2)
Out[30]: <_sre.SRE_Match object; span=(0, 46), match='as a result, we will comply with such standard'>

In [31]: re.search(str1, str3)
Out[31]: <_sre.SRE_Match object; span=(0, 41), match='as a result, we comply with such standard'>
```

If you put the "will " in parentheses and add the `{0,1}` it will find all instances where that clause exists 0 or 1 times. You mention `re.search` in the question title, but the code is using `re.findall`. I'm guessing you want search instead.

Difference between `re.search` and `re.findall`:

```
In [38]: re.search(str1, str2).group()
Out[38]: 'as a result, we will comply with such standard'


In [38]: re.search(str1, str2).group()
Out[38]: 'as a result, we will comply with such standard'

In [39]: re.findall(str1, "not in this string")
Out[39]: []

In [40]: re.findall(str1, str2)
Out[40]: ['will ']
```

Your code will work the same because of how an empty list evaluates to `False`. See this:

```
In [41]: bool(['will '])
Out[41]: True

In [42]: bool([])
Out[42]: False
```

Comment: A question mark (0 or 1 repetition) would make more sense than an asterisk (0 or more repetitions) here.  As shown, this will match "...we will will will will comply..."

Comment: Yea, I actually considered adding `{0, 1}` instead. and now I have

Comment: Thank you both. I actually look for re.findall(). Just edited the title. Isn't it more or less the same?

Comment: @martins not exactly. I updated my answer with some examples of the differences. Since `re.findall` returns an empty list, though, the end result will be the same in your code, because an empty list evaluates as `False` in Bool Land.